# Change default Timeouts for Sonar-class HttpDownloader

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

In SonarQube 5.0 there is a connection and read timeout set to 2000ms in class [HttpDownloader.java](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/e6740c707c8cc05051f8c0ac716d809809df43ce/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/utils/HttpDownloader.java).

Is there any possibility to increase that value? Or better: to set it manually by file sonar.properties?

This feature would be very helpful.
Maybe this can be consider in a future version.

Because at the moment i often have problems to read all plugin jars from the repository on time. Induced through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This could be very tempting to allow users to customize this timeout, because this would indeed fix issues like the one you currently have.

Still, we've decided to not offer this feature because this would just hide potential performance issues we can have on server-side. And we don't know to be blind about that. Instead, we want users to report us those failures so that we work on performance improvements rather than lying to ourselves. And for instance, this allows us to create tickets like [SONAR-6009](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6009).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

For sure, i can understand your point of view.
In my case there is no performance issue on server-side. The problem is the infrastructure of my local network. With a proxy and several security mechanism it tooks more than 20 seconds to retrieve a jar.

But please one other question concerning the retrieval of web resources: Is there a possibility to use another Artifactory/Cache server instead of the direct retrieval from the codehaus-repository? Any possibility to set an option?